General error: 1364 Field 'blog_id' doesn't have a default value
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'blog_id' doesn't have a default value (Connection: mysql, SQL: insert into comments (content, status, blogun_id, profilin_id, updated_at, created_at) values (vsvd, 1, 2, 2, 2024-07-20 23:36:02, 2024-07-20 23:36:02))
I try all solution ways I know but I can't fix this
This is my function to save data;
$validatedData = Validator::make($request->all(), [
             'comment' => 'required',
             'blog_id' => 'required',
        ]);

        if ($validatedData->fails()) {
            // Hata mesajlarını alın
            $errors = $validatedData->errors()->all(); // istersek laravelin kendi hatam mesajını da gönderebiliriz

            // E-posta veya şifrenin hatalı olduğunu belirten özel bir hata mesajı oluşturun
            $errorMessage = 'Girilen email veya şifre formatı hatalı!';

            // Hata mesajlarını kullanıcıya gösterin
            return redirect()->back()->with('error',$errors);
        }


            $comment = NEW Comment();
            $comment->content = $request->comment;
            $comment->status = true;
            $comment->blogun_id = (int)$request->blog_id;
            $comment->profilin_id = Auth::user()->profile->id;

            $comment->save();

And this is my comments migration;
Schema::create('comments', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();

            $table->string('content',250)->nullable(false);
            $table->boolean('status')->default(true)->comment('1 ise aktif, 0 ise kapalı');
            $table->bigInteger('blogun_id')->unsigned()->nullable(false);
            $table->bigInteger('profilin_id')->unsigned()->nullable(false);

            // bir blog veya profil birçok comment e sahip olabilir
            $table->foreignId('blog_id')->references('id')->on('blogs')->cascadeOnDelete();
            $table->foreignId('profile_id')->references('id')->on('profiles')->cascadeOnDelete();

            $table->timestamps();
        });

Error is in save() line , please help me

Did you add the column in in $fillable of your model?

In your migration file, you created 4 ids
blogun_id
profilin_id
blog_id
profile_id

However in your save code, you saved both blogun_id and profilin_id but not blog_id and profile_id. Make sure that you added it in your code:
$comment = NEW Comment();
$comment->content = $request->comment;
$comment->status = true;
$comment->blogun_id = (int)$request->blog_id;
$comment->profilin_id = Auth::user()->profile->id;

$comment->blog_id = /* whatever the blog id is */
$comment->profile_id = /* whatever the profile id is */

$comment->save();

Don't forget to include those ids in the fillable if your Comments model

I think you misunderstand how to use the $table->foreignId(). What you want to do is to add a foreign key constraints in the blogun_id column, right ?
There are 2 ways to add foreign key constraints in a column the first one is using the foreignId() and the other is using foreign().
Using the foreign()
$table->unsignedBigInteger('blogun_id'); // define the column
$table->foreign('blogun_id')->references('id')->on('blogs')->cascadeOnDelete(); // add the foreign key constraints

Using the foreignId()
$table->foreignId('blogun_id')->constrained('blogs')->cascadeOnDelete(); // Its the shortcut of foreignId()

$table->foreignId('blogun_id')->references('id')->on('blogs')->cascadeOnDelete();

So the difference between the two is the foreign one you can only use it in the already defined column if it is not defined it will produce an error while foreignId will work without defining a column first since it will automatically create a column for it.
In the snippet that you posted you are using foreignId() for creating the blog_id column. It means that you are creating the blog_id column with a foreign key constraints so the columns in your table are id,content,status,blogun_id,profilin_id,blog_id, and profile_id. Then when you are saving a data the only columns that are adding a data is content,status,blogun_id,profilin_id which makes the blog_id and profile_id null which produce a error since the 2 columns are not nullable

I noticed what you said too. Then I removed the blog_id and profile_id columns. Then I ran the migrate:fresh command. But I keep getting the same error when I try to add a new comment.

First checkout this line
$comment->blogun_id = (int)$request->blog_id;
You are validating blog_id and not blogun_id.
As the error said, you want to save blog_id in your database and the line I highighted will try to provide blogun_id into table which will not be accepted and blog_id will remain without the value which will cause the error you are getting.
Also, double check your mass-assignments in your model ($fillable) if you have blog_id or blogun_id there. It should match the name of the column in the migrations.
Good luck
